# comparing a xmmX vector

Tags: assembly, cmp, sse, eflags

So say you loaded an xmm1 vector with 4 single precision floating points {1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5} and xmm2 with the same points, so xmm1 == xmm2. 
Now you want to compare them so you write in assembly:

```
movaps  %xmm1, %xmm2
cmpeqps %xmm0, %xmm2
```

Since  *cmpeqps*  doesn't set the eflags, how can one say:

```
jne somewhere
```

Does one really need to use  *ucomiss*  to compare the right most portion of the vector, then shift right and repeat 3 more times?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `movaps` not `movss`. Use `PMOVMSKB` or branchless code if possible.

Comment: @Jester thank you for catching movaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cmpeqps`, you just have to extract the four flags. For example (not tested)

```
cmpeqps xmm2, xmm1
movmskps eax, xmm2
cmp eax, 15
je somewhere
```

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms for Vectorized arithmetics should be designed to avoid conditional branches. Instead each lane executes the same instructions. Conditions are generally performed by evaluating all possible results and selecting the correct with masks.